# Affine varietes and functions on closed points.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes of finite type over a field $k$. Assume that $X$ is geometrically reduced. If two morphisms $f,g$ from $X$ to $Y$ agree as maps on
$X(\bar{k}) \rightarrow Y(\bar{k})$ , I want to show that they are the same maps topologically. Here $\bar{k}$ denotes the algebraic closure. I can see they agree on closed points, but why do they agree on other points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ is a separated scheme, then the subset $K\subset X$ of points where $f$ and $g$ agree is closed in $X$.
If this set contains  the *dense* subset $X^{cl}\subset X$ of closed points of $X$, then $K=X$.

Note that density (and even very density)  of $X^{cl}$ is a general property of schemes locally of finite type over a field:cf. EGA IV, Troisième Partie, §10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . However, the book I am using has mot defined separated yet, which makes me curious if tere is another way.